# NHibernate Projection to DTO

Tags: web-services, nhibernate, orm, dto, projection

I am unfamiliar with NHibernate projection. I am attempting to use it so I can return a List<> rather that an IList<>. I am not having much luck with projecting to the DTO as of yet. I have the following query and Domain objects. So to begin I am just trying to get a list of Orders given an EmployeeID. I am looping through the resulting list and adding it to a List because I wish to be able to serialize this list. Can anyone tell me how far off I am with the Projection? I have searched and found some examples that are not similar to my own. Basically.. I just want to create a List of of the DTOs.

Thanks!

```
public List<EmployeeOrder> GetEmployessOrdersDTO(int empid)
        {
        var emporders = new List<EmployeeOrder>();

        ICriteria criteriaSelect = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession().CreateCriteria(typeof (Orders))
            .CreateCriteria("Employees")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("EmployeeID", empid));

        criteriaSelect.SetProjection(
            Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property("Products"), "OrderedProducts"));


        criteriaSelect.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(EmployeeOrder)));
        criteriaSelect.List<EmployeeOrder>();

        foreach (var order in emporders)
        {
            emporders.Add(order);
        }
        return emporders;
    }
```

Orders:

```
 public class Orders
{
    public virtual int OrderID { get; private set;}
    public virtual string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ShippedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Employees Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Products> Products { get; private set; }

}
```

Employees:

```
public class Employees
{

    public virtual int EmployeeID { get; private set;}
    public virtual string LastName { get; set;}
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set;}
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Orders> Orders { get; private set; }

}
```

EmployeeOrderDTO:

```
public class EmployeeOrder
{
    public virtual string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmployeeTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Products> OrderedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In nHibernate 2.1, the .List() method actually already returns a List type, so you can just cast:

```
var list = (List<EmployeeOrder>)criteriaSelect.List<EmployeeOrder>();
```

However, if you want to be future safe and not depend on assumptions based on the implementation of the current nHibernate, I'd write an extension method accepting ICriteria:

```
  public static List<T> ToList<T>(this ICriteria criteria)
  {
    return criteria.List<T>().ToList();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
criteriaSelect.List<EmployeeOrder>();
```

to

```
List<EmployeeOrder> employeeOrders = criteriaSelect.List<EmployeeOrder>() as List<EmployeeOrder>;
```